# How to consume empty collection without HAL response structure in spring-data-rest

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-4, spring-hateoas

I am using spring-data-rest in my application. I configured repositoryRest using [configureRepositoryRestConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.html#configureRepositoryRestConfiguration-org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration-)

I added the following two lines in this configuration

```
config.exposeIdsFor(Person.class);
config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
```

Before adding this configuration my response looks as follows

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "persons": []
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://192.168.2.42:8082/persons/search/findByGroupId?groupId=44"
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to get the empty person list using RestTemplate as expected. But after adding the above configuration, I am getting the following response structure

```
{
  "links": [{
    "rel": "self",
    "href": "http://localhost:8082/persons/search/findByGroupId?groupId=44"
  }],
  "content": [{
    "collectionValue": true,
    "relTargetType": "com.myapp.example.domain.Person",
    "value": []
  }]
}
```

with this response `RestTemplate` returns a list of size 1 containing `null` values for all attributes in my domain.

Can anyone help to get empty list with this structure.

I used the following code to get response from API:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    url, 
    GET, 
    HttpEntity.EMPTY, 
    parameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Person>>, 
    Collections.emptyMap()
);
```

**UPDATE:**

Is this a spring-data-rest bug. Because somewhere in code, instead of `Person`, `EmbeddedWrapper` is used as a domain type. After investigating the code, I found the `"collectionValue"`, `"relTargetType"`, and `"value"` in JSON response are deserialized from `EmbeddedWrapper` class.

Refer: [EmbeddedWrappers.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/core/EmbeddedWrappers.java#L59)

Comment: Hi @Achaius, have you found a solution for this? I'm struggling with the same odd behaviour from SDR.